# Object of type GeoPoint is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, firebase, flask, firebase-realtime-database, flash-message

I want to create an API that has to recover data from firestore and expose them in json but I am facing the error of:

```
Object of type GeoPoint is not JSON serializable
```

What's wrong? This My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import firebase_admin
import json
from pprint import pprint as pp
from flask import Flask, flash, request, url_for, jsonify, Response
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

app = Flask(__name__)

cred = credentials.Certificate('xxxx.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()

@app.route('/')
def index():

    markers_ref = db.collection(u'Test')
    docs = markers_ref.get()

    data = []
    for doc in docs:
        data.append(doc.to_dict())

    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    resp = Response(json_data, status=200, mimetype='application/json')

    return resp

if __name__=='__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: It says _"Object (eg: data list) of type GeoPoint cannot be made as JSON text"_ so try to get JSON from some Text / String data. Maybe you have another step to do? (eg parse / convert the **Geopoint** type into **Object** type).

Answer (score 2):

Following should do the trick -

```
from flask import (Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, render_template, flash, Response, jsonify)
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import firestore

@app.route('/foods/<id>')
def read_food(id):

    result=FOODS.document(id).get().to_dict()
    record = {}
    # Populate the new dict with JSON serializiable values
    for key in result:
        if isinstance(result[key], firebase_admin.firestore.GeoPoint):
            record[key] =str(result[key].latitude)+','+str(result[key].longitude)
            continue
        record[key] = result[key]

    # Add the key so that we have a reference to the record
    record['key'] = result[key]

    return jsonify(record)
```